# Quotient of compact metrizable space in Hausdorff space

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

Lets $X$ be a compact metrizable space and $f:X\to Y$ be a quotient map such that $Y$ equipped with the quotient topology is Hausdorff. Thus $Y$ is metrizable. Lets $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$ such that $x\sim y$ if $f(x)=f(y)$. Then for any metric $d$ compatible with the topology of $X$ one can build a (pseudo)metric $d_\sim$ on $Y$ with:
\begin{equation}
d_\sim(a,b) = \inf\{d(p_1,q_1) + \cdots+ d(p_n,q_n);[p_1] = a,[q_i] =
[p_{i+1}],[q_n] = b\}.(1)
\end{equation}
Where the $\inf$ is taken over all finite chains of points $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^n$ between $a$ and $b$.

As in this question which has not been fully answered ([Quotient of metric spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195611/quotient-of-metric-spaces))
 can we show that $d_\sim$ is a metric compatible with the quotient topology in $Y$ ?

If not, what would be a sufficient condition on the quotient map in order to have the result ?

Here is an attempt:

In Herman 1968, *Quotient of metric spaces*, in theorem 4.8, is stated the following :

> **THEOREM**:
>   Let $f$ be a function from a pseudo-metrizable space $X$ to a topological space $Y$, and suppose that $Y$ has the quotient topology relative to $f$, then the following are equivalent:
>   1) $Y$ is pseudo-metrizable
>   2) There exists a pseudo-metric $\rho$ compatible with the topology in $X$ such that the quotient pseudo-metric $\rho_\sim$, defined as in (1), is in fact compatible with the quotient topology of $Y$ (The definition of the quotient pseudo-metric by Herman should be equivalent to the one introduced earlier).

If $X$ is in fact metrizable, then it is pseudo-metrizable and $Y$ is also pseudo-metrizable. Therefore, from the theorem there exists a pseudo-metric $d^*$ compatible with the topology in $X$ (it is a metric as $X$ is Hausdorff) such that the quotient pseudo-metric $d^*_\sim$ is compatible with the topology in $Y$ (it is also a metric because $Y$ is Hausdorff too).

Is it possible to show that any quotient (pseudo)metric from an arbitrary metric $d$ is topologically equivalent to $d^*_\sim$ ?

We know that $X$ is metrizable and compact, thus there is a unique uniform structure in it and all metrics compatible with the topology are uniformly equivalent. Therefore any metric $d$ compatible with the topology of $X$ is uniformly equivalent to the metric $d^*$.

From uniform equivalent metrics, maybe there is a relation between their corresponding quotient pseudo-metrics but I am stucked here, do you have any idea/theorem/reference that would help me ?

Thanks

Comment: According to the  first  line  of your  post, I think  $Y$ is  always  metrizable, provided it is  Haussdorf. (No  quotion topology is  needed for  its  metrizability). am  I  mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

For [the Cantor starcase function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) $f:C\to[0,1]$ from the standard ternary Cantor set $C$ onto the interval $[0,1]$ and for the standard Euclidean metric $d$ on $C$ the quotient pseudometric $d_\sim$ is constant zero (this follows from the fact that the Cantor set $C$ has length zero). So, the pseudometric $d_\sim$ is not necessarily a metric.

This example should be known but I cannot mention a suitable reference at the moment.

**Added in Edit.** Essentially the same counterexample is discussed in the answer of Wlodzimierz Holsztynski to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195611/quotient-of-metric-spaces).

Comment: Thank for the answer ! Indeed it is the same counter-example than in the question I have quoted. However, I have realised that I need to deal with path-connected spaces so that quotient space is path-connected in the quotient pseudo-metric. Is there a known example that does not use the cantor set ?

Comment: @VMrcel You can extend the Cantor starcase function to a continuous function on the closed interval and then you will get a continuous function between closed intervals, for which the quotient pseudometric still is zero. By the way, the quotient space is path-connected in the quotient metric (since it determines the anti-discrete topology). So, maybe some more precise question should be asked (but a good question is a half of an answer).

Comment: Oh you are right, I'll think about it, thank you !