# What is the quotient (pseudo)metric $d_\sim$ and how do I identify the infimum of possible sequences in this instance?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, collatz-conjecture, quotient-space

Let $Z$ be the the set of dyadic and ternary rationals in the interval $\left[\frac12,1\right)$ whose 3-adic valuation is either $-1$ or $0$, with the standard absolute value topology inherited from the real line.

Let $X=\{z\in Z:\nu_3(x)=0\}$.

Let $Y=\{z\in Z:\nu_3(x)=-1\}$.

Now define an equivalence relation $\sim$ which partitions $Z$ into equivalence classes $\{x, y\}$ of cardinality $2$ with $x \in X$, $y \in Y$, and $f(x) = y$, where $f:X\to Y$ is given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{4x}3 &\text{if}& x<\frac34\\
\frac{2x}3& \text{if}& x>\frac34.\end{cases}$$

So for example $\frac5{8}\sim\frac56$ and $\frac{7}{8}\sim\frac{7}{12}$.

The quotient (pseudo)metric $d_\sim$ on $Z/{\sim}$ is the infimum distance by which one can traverse from any equivalence class to another, by stepping on up to infinitely many equivalence classes in-between and summing only the distance *between* classes and not the distance travelled *within* classes.  More formally this is defined at [@EricWofsey's answer to "Is there a conceptual reason why topological spaces have quotient structures while metric spaces don't?"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/123753/91341).

**Question**

I seek an explicit definition of $d_\sim$ in this instance.  Of course, in a sense Eric's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/123753/91341) does give that, but it leaves me with a requirement to somehow iterate over all possible sequences of equivalence classes and determine the shortest path, something well beyond my capabilities.

**Also Note**

While this question stands alone without reference to the Collatz conjecture, I feel more comfortable declaring that identifying this metric is a component of my study of the conjecture, partly in the spirit of full-disclosure, but also becase it may be material to the answer, to be mindful of the following observations:

- $g(x)=x+\frac132^{\nu_2(x)}$ is both a surjection $X\to Y$ and a surjection $Z/{\sim}\to Z/{\sim}$ and seen as a map $g:Z/{\sim}\to Z/{\sim}$ it is essentially the Collatz graph and its graph is connected if and only if the Collatz conjecture is true.  One should not be surprised therefore, if some proof that $d_\sim$ is the trivial metric, $\forall [z_0],[z_1]:d_\sim([z_0],[z_1])=0$, were related to the claim that the graph of the orbit of $g$ through $Z/{\sim}$ is connected.
- The $n$-indexed sequences of the form $s_n(x)=x+(1-2^{-6n})\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$ form an exact cover of $X$ (up to subsequences) and $g$ is their infinite limit.  Moreover, for every $y\in Y$ there are precisely two $s_n$ (up to subsequences) whose union is the level set by $g$ of $y$.
- If $d_\sim$ is not the trivial (pseudo)metric, it seems likely a proof that some sequence gives the infimum for the metric may use the sequences given in the two bullets above.
- This question has a "dual", if you like, which is to enquire into the quotient pseudometric obtained when setting $x\sim' g(x)$ instead of $x\sim f(x)$ and moreover the conjecture is equivalent to the claim that $Z/({\sim}\cdot{\sim'})$ is a singleton having $Z$ as its only element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One gets the trivial semi-distance. Let $d$ denote the semi-distance on $Z$ that defines $d_\sim$ on $Z/\sim$, that is $d_\sim([z],[z']):=d(z,z')$ for all $z$ and $z'$ in $Z$. Thus $d(z,z')\le |z-z'|$ for all $z$ and $z'$ in $Z$  and $d(x,f(x))=0$ for all $x\in X$.

It is convenient to extend the definition of $f$ to a self-map $[1/2,1)\to[1/2,1)$, still denoted $f$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{4x}3 &\text{if}& 0\le x<\frac34\\
\frac{2x}3& \text{if}&  \frac34\le x <1.\end{cases}$$

The key point is that *all orbits of $f$ are dense*. So for every $z$ and $z'$ in $Z$, and for every $\epsilon>0$, there is $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $\lvert f^m(z)-z'\rvert< \epsilon$. Since $X$ is also dense, and since $f$ is everywhere (right) continuous, for all indices $ 0\le j\le m$ there are $x_j\in X$ such that
\begin{align*}
\bigl\lvert f^j(z)-x_j\bigr\rvert<\frac\epsilon m, & \qquad (0\le j\le m) \\
\bigl\lvert f(x_j)-f^{j+1}(z)\bigr\rvert<\frac\epsilon m, & \qquad (0\le j\le m-1).
\end{align*}
Therefore for $0\le j\le m-1$
$$\bigl\lvert f(x_j)-x_{j+1}\bigr\rvert \le \bigl\lvert f(x_j)-f^{j+1}(z)\bigr\rvert+\bigl\lvert f^{j+1}(z)-x_{j+1}\bigr\rvert\le \frac{2\epsilon}m$$
and
$$d(z,z')\le\bigl\lvert z-x_0\bigr\rvert+ \bigg(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} \bigl\lvert f(x_j)-x_{j+1}\bigr\rvert \bigg) +\big|x_m-z'\big|\le 4\epsilon,$$
which proves that $d$ vanishes identically.

*All orbits of $f$ are dense*: Indeed, having all orbits dense is a property invariant by conjugation, and $f$ is conjugate to the irrational translation (modulo $1$) on $[0,1)\sim\mathbb{R/Z }$ given by $T_c:x\mapsto {x -c}$, where  $c:=\frac {\log 3}{\log 2}-1$ (all orbits of a  translation  $T_c$ are dense iff $c$ is irrational).

Consider the homeomorphism $h:[0,1)\to[1/2,1)$ defined by $h(x)=2^{x-1}$. Then it is easy to check that $h\circ T_c=f \circ h$.

Comment: Thank-you most kindly. This will take some time for me to digest properly to my lack of skill but I think the gist is that the pseudometric is $d_\sim=0$. Does this necessarily push through to the quotient space not being Hausdorff? I assume not because the quotient space is richer than the quotient metric.

Comment: P.S. was this fairly instantly obvious to a better mathematician than I, or did it take some degree of thought? It seems fairly obvious the way you put it about every orbit being dense - must imply the distances between them are zero.

Comment: I think so (quotient being Hausdorff)  but I do not see immediately.

Comment: On the PS: To me, it was not obvious, and I wasn't even sure that the distance was trivial. How I proceeded, it's nothing special, but here it is. 1) It seemed that $X$ and $Y$ do not play a special role in studying these objects, and that it is healthier to have $f$ as a self-map, to make iterations. 2) one works better on the interval, than on the quotient.

Comment: 3) in this semi-distance, $1/2$ is close to the right-end, for $f(3/4-\epsilon)= 1-4\epsilon/3$ and $f(3/4+\epsilon)= 1/2-2\epsilon/3$. So nothing changes if one starts from a circle, identifying the endpoints of $[1/2,1]$, instead using $[1/2,1)$, which makes $f$ a homeomorphism. This allows to use the tools of homeomorphims of the circle. I wrote $f$  as a time-1 flow to compute its rotation number and find a conjugation with a rotation: only at the end I realized the conjugation was so easy.

Comment: PS: The quotient (semi)distance $\tilde d$ on $\tilde X$ for a quotient $\pi:X\to\tilde X$ is the maximum (semi)distance on $\tilde X$ that makes $\pi$ a $1$-Lipschitz map. This leads to the construction of $\tilde d$ via chains of jumps from a class to anothe (which I would call *the construction* rather than *the definition* of $\tilde d$ ).

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be a proof (sorry if it wasn't clear). Having every  orbit  dense is a conjugation invariant (recall that $f=hgh^{-1}\Rightarrow f^m=hg^mh^{-1}$ for all $m$), and the translation $x\mapsto x+c\mod 1$ on $\mathbb{ T:=R/Z}$ does have every orbit dense if (and only if) $c$ is irrational (for the orbit of $x$ is  $x+c \mathbb Z\mod 1 $), so  every orbit of $f$ is dense too.

Comment: Don't worry, it is perfectly normal that we sometimes miss something, and we have the right to ask any question --even because sometimes "trivialities" hide not-at-all-trivial facts.

Comment: It seems LSpice overlooked the condition in the first sentence: *whose $3$-adic valuation is either $−1$ or $0$*.  This constrains the equivalence classes to have cardinality two.  I'm just checking you didn't overlook the same, and whether your answer still stands notwithstanding this?

Comment: You don't really need to quotient, as your quotient set $Z/\sim$ can be identified with $X$. Alternatively, you may even consider $f$ on all rationals, and quotient on the $\mathbb Z$ action, so that equivelence classes are the whole orbits of $f$. Any class then contains exactly one element  of $X$.

Comment: I'm sorry to push for more - please feel free to ignore.  This is to do with the motivation behind this question:  Consider the $n$-indexed sequence $\dfrac{2^{6n+2}-1}6=\frac12,\frac{85}{128},\frac{5461}{8192}\ldots$. This converges in $\Bbb R$ to $\frac23$ and in $\Bbb Q_2$ to $-\frac16$. In the trivial pseudometric here it trivially converges as it's the identity sequence. But it also converges to $[\frac12\sim\frac23]$ in the quotient topology (non-pseudometric). Any pointers how I might attempt to derive/construct this quotient topology and show it is Hausdorff or nontrivial?

Comment: ok but which quotient topology?

Comment: Simply $Z/{\sim}$ in the quotient topology as per https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3810857/334732 which may be stronger than the quotient pseudometric.  I.e. the standard absolute value metric from $\Bbb R$ reduced by the equivalence relation $\sim$. Or maybe it's no stronger and it coincides with the pseudometric topology in this particular case?

Comment: So you mean the quotient topology on $Z/\!\sim$ for the  topological space $Z$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb R$) and the equivalence relation, as defined in your post here?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  That is the ultimate motivation of this question... I hoped this question would either be it, or be a stepping stone towards it.  The convergent sequences or open sets I'm interested have the recurrence relation $x_{n+1}=x_n+21\cdot2^{\nu_2(x_n)-6}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x_n)}$

Comment: Thank-you.  This will provide a good month or two of food for thought for me. I am much obliged to you.

Comment: Topologic conjugacy, as it is written in the last line.

Comment: @samerivertwice, I [agree](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/380398): $(f \circ h)(x) = \frac{2^{x + 1}}3 = 2^{x - \log_2(3) + 1} = h(x - c + 1)$ for $x < c$, and $(f \circ h)(x) = \frac{2^x}3 = 2^{(x - \log_2(3) + 1) - 1} = h(x - c)$ for $x \ge c$.

Comment: You say I don't really need to quotient as the quotient can be identified with $X$. I want to show $g=x+\frac{21}{64}\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ converges on transfinite iteration.

For some $x:\lvert x\rvert_3=1$, the infinite limit of $g^n(x)$ satisfies $\lvert x\rvert_3=3$. Fine, so apply $f^{-1}$ and I'm back in $X$. Therefore I can just use $j(x)=f^{-1}\circ \lim_{n\to\infty}g^n:X\to X$. Does your $h$ help me with the proof that $j$ converges on iteration? The claim that it does converge is equivalent to the Collatz conjecture.